# blocks attached to each other

Tags: technical-drawing

For my thesis, I often need to write blocks attached to each other. More explicitely, I want to have blocks as in page 13 of http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/392.pdf.

**EDIT**: @morbusg. Is it possible to (easily?) fix the following (in order to get what we want)

```
 \begin{figure}
 \centerline{\vbox{%
   \offinterlineskip % no lead between lines
   \dimen0=4.5em % size of a square cell
   \mathsurround0pt % precaution; although I've newer seen it used
   \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\hrule}} % put a rule between every row with \cr
   \halign{&\vrule\hbox to\dimen0{$\vcenter to\dimen0{}\hfil\scriptstyle#\hfil$}\crcr
     \omit& \omit& \multispan3\hrulefill\crcr\noalign{\kern-.4pt}
     % ^omit drawing a box for the first two columns, then, span the next
     % three columns drawing the "hat", and finally, back up the amount of
     % the width of the rule so that the vertical and horizontal rules
     % fit together.
     \omit& \omit&\omit & W(-k-1,1) & W(-k,1) & W(-k+1,1) &\omit\vrule \cr
     W(-k-4,0) & W(-k-3,0) & W(-k-2,0) & W(-k-1,0) & W(-k,0) & W(-k+1,0) & W(-k+2,0) & W(-k+3,0)&\omit\vrule \cr
     }
 }}
 \caption{}
 \end{figure}
```

And also

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\centerline{\vbox{%
  \offinterlineskip % no lead between lines
  \dimen0=5em % size of a square cell
  \mathsurround0pt % precaution; although I've newer seen it used
  \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\hrule}} % put a rule between every row with \cr
  \halign{&\vrule\hbox to\dimen0{$\vcenter to\dimen0{}\hfil\scriptstyle#\hfil$}\crcr
    \omit& \omit& \multispan3\hrulefill\crcr\noalign{\kern-.4pt}
    % ^omit drawing a box for the first two columns, then, span the next
    % three columns drawing the "hat", and finally, back up the amount of
    % the width of the rule so that the vertical and horizontal rules
    % fit together.
    \omit        & W(k-1,2n+2)   & W(k,2n+2) & W(k+1,2n+2) & ? &\omit\vrule \cr
    ? & W(k-1,2n+1) & W(k,2n+1) & W(k+1,2n+1)   & ? &\omit\vrule \cr
    ? & W(k-1,2n)   & W(k,2n)   & W(k+1,2n)   & ?  &\omit\vrule \cr
    ? & W(k-1,2n-1) & W(k,2n-1) & W(k+1,2n-1)   & ? &\omit\vrule \cr
    }
}}
\label{Sdouble}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: This is an ideal place to use [`xcoffins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins).

Comment: The `&` character is the column separator character. The `\omit` omits the preamble definition taking place in the cell it is called in. The `\multispan` takes a number as its first argument which tells how many columns it ought to span, and the `\hrulefill` fills the cell content with a rule (/line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[34]
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\vbox{%
  \offinterlineskip % no lead between lines
  \dimen0=4em % size of a square cell
  \mathsurround0pt % precaution; although I've newer seen it used
  \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\hrule}} % put a rule between every row with \cr
  \halign{&\vrule\hbox to\dimen0{$\vcenter to\dimen0{}\hfil\scriptstyle#\hfil$}\crcr
    \omit& \omit& \multispan3\hrulefill\crcr\noalign{\kern-.4pt}
    % ^omit drawing a box for the first two columns, then, span the next
    % three columns drawing the "hat", and finally, back up the amount of
    % the width of the rule so that the vertical and horizontal rules
    % fit together.
    \omit& \omit& (k-1,1) & (k,1) & (k+1,1) &\omit\vrule \cr
    (k-3,0) & (k-2,0) & (k-1,0) & (k,0) & (k+1,0) & (k+2,0) & (k+3,0) & (k+4,0)&\omit\vrule \cr
    }
}}
\caption{Boxes boxes everywhere}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could make a macro for it, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\myboxything#1#2{\vbox{%
  \def\hatfor##1{\multispan{##1}\hrulefill\crcr\noalign{\kern-.4pt}}
  \offinterlineskip
  \mathsurround=0pt
  \def\cr{&\omit\vrule\crcr\noalign{\hrule}}
  \halign{&\vrule\hbox to#1{$\vcenter to#1{}\hfil\scriptstyle##\hfil$}\crcr
    #2\cr}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[34]

\begin{figure}
\centerline{\myboxything{4em}{%
  \multispan2& \hatfor3
  \multispan2& (k-1,1)& (k,1)& (k+1,1) \cr
  (k-3,0)& (k-2,0)& (k-1,0)& (k,0)& (k+1,0)& (k+2,0)& (k+3,0)& (k+4,0)}
}
\caption{Boxes boxes everywhere}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{\myboxything{4.5em}{%
  \multispan3& \hatfor3
  \multispan3& W(-k-1,1)& W(-k,1)& W(-k+1,1) \cr
  W(-k-4,0)& W(-k-3,0)& W(-k-2,0)& W(-k-1,0)& W(-k,0)& W(-k+1,0)& W(-k+2,0)&
    W(-k+3,0)}
}
\caption{Even more boxes}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{\myboxything{5.5em}{%
  \omit& \hatfor4
  \omit& W(k-1,2n+2)& W(k,2n+2)& W(k+1,2n+2)& ? \cr
  ?& W(k-1,2n+1)& W(k,2n+1)& W(k+1,2n+1)& ? \cr
  ?& W(k-1,2n)& W(k,2n)& W(k+1,2n)& ? \cr
  ?& W(k-1,2n-1)& W(k,2n-1)& W(k+1,2n-1)& ?}
}
\caption{Boxy lady}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the above code not work correctly if I want to "omit" the first 3 blocks instead of the first two? If add one time \omit& the result is (for the first row, the second row is ok): 
the first two blocks are empty, the third block has a rule at the top, the sixth block has no rule at the top.

Comment: @Nadori: because the “hat” is in the row above, so one would need to add the omit there as well. Admittedly, this is by no means an easy to understand way to build such constructs, but it is much, much lighter than TikZ.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question above. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

You could use TikZ …

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{block/.style={minimum size=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,draw,rectangle,node distance=0pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={block},]
   \node (A) {$k=1$};
   \node (B) [left=of A] {$k=2$};
   \node (C) [left=of B] {$k=3$};
   \node (D) [right=of A] {$k=0$};
   \node (E) [above=of B] {$i=1$};
   \node (F) [right=of E] {$i=2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Take a look at the manual for more information

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. It's never described in the current `pgfmanual`, but funny often used there. The official way would be to use `\tikzset{block/.style={minimum size=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,draw,rectangle,node distance=0pt}`. The expression can also be used in the optional argument of `tikzpicture`, e.g. to keep it local if wanted.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Funny … I normally use `\tikzset{...` but I saw `\tikzstyle` so often that I thought it’s the preferred way. Then I’ll use `\tikzset` it’s even my preferred code :-)

Comment: The `pgfmanual` really needs some updating in this regard! ;-)

Comment: How can I add a caption?

Comment: @Nadori: Use a `{figure}` or try the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) to make your own float environment. Furthermore you may need `\captionof{<type>}{<caption>}` (form KOMA-Script classes or with [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)) to type the caption outside of floating environments. If this doesn’t help pleas consider the LaTeX (beginners) guide of your preference ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, here is an example of how you can use the [`xcoffins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) package to produce the same result.

I use some boxes through `\mybox` command, and positioned them using `xcoffins`. For more information on the positioning capabilities of the package you can check the [manual](http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental/xcoffins.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{{\fbox{\vbox to #1 {\vfill \hbox to #1 {#2} \vfill}}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\NewCoffin \main
\SetHorizontalCoffin \main {\mybox{40pt}{$i=1$}}
\NewCoffin \Ab
\SetHorizontalCoffin \Ab {\mybox{40pt}{$i=2$}}
\NewCoffin \Ba
\SetHorizontalCoffin \Ba {\mybox{40pt}{$k=3$}}
\NewCoffin \Bb
\SetHorizontalCoffin \Bb {\mybox{40pt}{$k=2$}}
\NewCoffin \Bc
\SetHorizontalCoffin \Bc {\mybox{40pt}{$k=1$}}
\NewCoffin \Bd
\SetHorizontalCoffin \Bd {\mybox{40pt}{$k=0$}}

% Join \main using the (r)ight (v)ertical (c)enter with the \Ab (l)eft (v)ertical (c)enter
\JoinCoffins \main[r,vc] \Ab[l,vc]
% Join using the (l)eft (b)ottom and the (r)ight (t)op
\JoinCoffins \main[l,b] \Ba[r,t]
% Join \Bb (and others) to \main using the handles from \Ba
\JoinCoffins \main[\Ba-r,\Ba-vc] \Bb[l,vc]
\JoinCoffins \main[\Bb-r,\Bb-vc] \Bc[l,vc]
\JoinCoffins \main[\Bc-r,\Bc-vc] \Bd[l,vc]

\TypesetCoffin \main

\end{document}
```

[image: coffins example]