# Tikz Chains with one side of the leftmost node, thickbold

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning everybody.
This is actually the first time I write here, so thanks to anyone who is going to reply.
I am writing my undergraduate thesis and I am currently stuck at drawing a Turing Machine. What I'd like to do is something like this:

[image]

Except that I'd like to have the left side of the first node (only the left side, not all 4 sides) in verythick. What I've done until now is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\turingtapesize{0.7cm}
\tikzstyle{tape}=[draw,minimum size=\turingtapesize]
\tikzset{
    leftmostnode/.style={
        draw,minimum size=\turingtapesize,
        append after command={% <= for the leftside line of the leftward node
            \pgfextra{%
            \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
            \begin{pgfonlayer}[foreground]
                \draw[verythick] (\tikzlastnode.south west)--(\tikzlastnode.north west);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \end{pgfinterruptpath}
            }
        }
    }
}

% Drawing the tape itself
\begin{scope}[start chain=0 going right,node distance=0mm]
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (b)  {0};
    \node[left=of b,leftmostnode](a){1};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (c)  {1};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (d)  {0};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (e)  {1};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (f)  {0};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (g)  {0};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (h)  {1};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (i)  {1};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (l)  {$\sqcup$};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (l)  {$\sqcup$};
    \node[on chain=0,tape] (l)  {$\sqcup$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I get an error:

> Sorry, the requested layer '[' could not be found. Maybe you misspelled it?.
>
> \nodeleft=of b,leftmostnode {1};

May I also ask you how to get that kind of 'chainsawed' (does this term even exist?) end of the tape?
Thanks, cheers ;)
Source: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76459/how-to-modify-nodes-in-tikz-to-automatically-add-a-line-on-their-top) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49839/turing-machine-figure)

EDIT 
As suggested by moospit, I worked around the 'thickness problem'. Now it remains me only to create that special-jagged-line ;)

EDIT2
I've just seen your reply. I solved it in a slightly different way.. I post below the code of the whole tikz-image ;)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\turingtapesize{0.7cm}
\tikzstyle{tape}=[draw,minimum size=\turingtapesize]

% Drawing the tape itself
\begin{scope}[start chain=0 going right,node distance=0mm]
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (a)     {1}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (b)     {0}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (c)     {1}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (d)     {0}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (e)     {1}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (f)     {0}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (g)     {0}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (h)     {1}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (i)     {1}       ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (l)     {$\sqcup$};
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (l)     {$\sqcup$};
    \node[on chain=0,tape]          (l)     {$\sqcup$};
    \node[on chain=0,tape,draw=none](m)     {}        ;
    \node[on chain=0,tape,draw=none](n)     {$\ldots$};

% Coordinates
    \coordinate(snake1) at ($ (l.north east)!0.5cm!(m.north east) $);
    \coordinate(snake2) at ($ (l.south east)!.5cm!(m.south east) $) ;

    \draw [-] (l.north east) -- (snake1);
    \draw [-] (l.south east) -- (snake2);
    \draw[snake=snake,
        segment amplitude=.4mm,
            segment length=1.75mm,
        line after snake=0mm] (snake1) -- (snake2);
\end{scope}

    \draw[ultra thick] (a.south west) -- (a.north west)                   ;
    \node[draw,above=0.75cm of e,minimum size=\turingtapesize] (Q) {$q_3$};
    \draw[-latex] (Q) -- (e)                                              ;     
\end{tikzpicture}
```

> EDIT3

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{tape/.style={minimum size=.7cm, draw}}
  \begin{scope}[start chain=0 going right, node distance=0mm]
   \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,$\sqcup$,$\sqcup$,$\sqcup$} {
    \ifnum\i=12 % if last node reset outer sep to 0pt
      \node [on chain=0, tape, outer sep=0pt] (n\i) {\x};
      \draw (n\i.north east) -- ++(.1,0) decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=.12cm, amplitude=.02cm}] {-- ($(n\i.south east)+(+.1,0)$)} -- (n\i.south east) -- cycle;
     \else
      \node [on chain=0, tape] (n\i) {\x};
     \fi
     \ifnum\i=1 % if first node draw a thick line at the left
      \draw [line width=.1cm] (n\i.north west) -- (n\i.south west);
     \fi
   }
   \node [right=.25cm of n12] {$\cdots$};
   \node [tape, above left=.25cm and 1cm of n1] (q3) {$q_3$};
   \draw [>=latex, ->] (q3) -| (n5);
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

And here the final result:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using your `tape` style for node `a` and just adding this after your chain code:

```
\draw [very thick] (a.south west) -- (a.north west);
```

or

```
\draw [line width=.1cm] (a.south west) -- (a.north west);
```

This way you can add an additional line drawn above your node `a`.

[image: rendered image]

> **EDIT:** Update on your zigzag-node at the end of the chain (MWE)

Here also some information on your zigzag-node. I used the `zigzag`-decoration on a part of the below described path. Just adjust the `zigzag` `segment length` and amplitude` to your needs.

Watch out to set the `outer sep` of your chain-nodes to `0`, else the zigzag path will get some offset from the `north east` and `south east` coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, calc}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, outer sep=0pt] (n) {n};
  \draw (n.north east) -- ++(.1,0) decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=.12cm, amplitude=.02cm}] {-- ($(n.south east)+(+.1,0)$)} -- (n.south east) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

> **JUST ONE MORE EDIT:** couldn't resist ;). Little rewrite of your code to make the chain extendable for more elements:

If you got more questions just ask. You can easily change the `zigzag` with some `snakes` if you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{tape/.style={minimum size=.7cm, draw}}
  \begin{scope}[start chain=0 going right, node distance=0mm]
   \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1,0,1,10,1,1,1,1,$\sqcup$,$\sqcup$,$\sqcup$} {
    \ifnum\i=11 % if last node reset outer sep to 0pt
      \node [on chain=0, tape, outer sep=0pt] (n\i) {\x};
      \draw (n\i.north east) -- ++(.1,0) decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=.12cm, amplitude=.02cm}] {-- ($(n\i.south east)+(+.1,0)$)} -- (n\i.south east) -- cycle;
     \else
      \node [on chain=0, tape] (n\i) {\x};
     \fi
     \ifnum\i=1 % if first node draw a thick line at the left
      \draw [line width=.1cm] (n\i.north west) -- (n\i.south west);     
     \fi
   }
   \node [right=.25cm of n11] {$\cdots$};
   \node [tape, above left=.25cm and 1cm of n1] (q7) {$q_7$};
   \draw [>=latex, ->] (q7) -| (n5); 
  \end{scope}  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Comment: Ohhhh myyy Gosh.. Yeah bro, it worked!! I just wonder why I haven't thought about it before.. It should be elementary -.-
:-)
Thanks moospit

Comment: I've just seen your reply. Since I cannot put the entire 'new'-image code, I edit the first post and reply you there (under EDIT2):
Thanks for you support <3

Comment: Sorry for not having replied you earlier. Thanks for having improved once again the code. Now the image on my paper is absolutely perfect! I will cite you in the acknowledgements if you give me your 'permission' ;)

Comment: I'd be pleased ;)

Comment: Ok then! ;) It will be done Sir ;)
I've further re-edited your last code section to replace two little oversights. Since the code would be too long to be pasted in here, I'll inster it in the first post right after EDIT3. Thanks again for all your support. ;)