# Array with arrows and a cell outside

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the array in the picture with a cell outside, the arrows, the border and some cells coloured. Could you please tell me how? [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/ or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/chains/

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203257/tikz-chains-with-one-side-of-the-leftmost-node-thickbold might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time, please provide a Minimum Working Example. Here is a beginning...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, arrows.meta, bending, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    -{Stealth[length=2.5pt]},
    every node/.style={draw, text width=25pt, text centered},
    my arrow/.style={shape=single arrow, rotate=90, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, single arrow head extend=1pt, minimum height=7.5pt, text width=0pt, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!25}
  ]
  \begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=0pt]
    \node [on chain] (2) {2};
    \node [on chain] (4) {4};
    \node [on chain] (1 phantom) {\phantom{1}};
    \node [on chain] (3) {3};
  \end{scope}
  \node (1) [below=15pt of 1 phantom] {1};
  \draw (1 phantom.south) -- (1.north);
  \draw (2.north) [out=25, in=155] to (4.north);
  \draw (4.north) [out=25, in=155] to (1 phantom.north);
  \node [below=2.5pt of 2.south, anchor=east, my arrow] {};
  \node [below=2.5pt of 3.south, anchor=east, my arrow] {};
\draw [draw=yellow, thick, opacity=.75] (4.south east) +(0,-2.5pt) -- (4.north east) -- +(0,2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ticker tape]

Comment: I will, thank you for your advice! can you help me with drawing the yellow vertical line in the picture?

Comment: @user3062963 See updated answer.