# Curved arrow on top of table

Tags: tables, tikz-arrows

Does any know how to put an arrow on top of a table in latex? Got the feeling I need tikzmark. But wasn't able to get the arrow at the right position.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \tikzmark{b}4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 12 & 8\tikzmark{a} & 7 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 14 & 13 & 15 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [<-] (a) [bend left] to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, in future provide complete small document which start with `\documentclass{...}`, continued by essential used packages, `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also use figure environment option `[H]` is measure of last resort if other options doesn't work as you expected. In your case use of `[htb]` is just fine.

Comment: See also [proportional boxes in Tikz (array diagram)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245251/4778)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

in your MWE you are quit close to what you looking for. Suppose, that in your preamble is `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` than correct syntax for arrows coordinate is for example `(pic cs:b)`. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=11mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
4\tikzmark{b} & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 12 & \tikzmark{a}8 & 7 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 14 & 13 & 15 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [<-,red] ([yshift=3ex]pic cs:b) [bend left] to ([yshift=3ex]pic cs:a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** if you change position of `tikzmarks` to after and before cell content, the arrow will be tetter positioned.  This change is now considered in MWE.

Answer (score 1):

TikZ is not the only easy solutions: you can also do it with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{array}%
 \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{postscript}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{15}{c|}}
      \hline
      \pnode[0.5ex, 2.5ex]{b} 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 12 & \pnode[0.5ex, 2.5ex]{a} 8 & 7 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 14 & 13 & 15 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \psset{arrows=->, linecolor=IndianRed}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-30]{a}{b}
    \ncangle[angle=-90, nodesep=2.8ex]{a}{b}
  \end{postscript}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]